# Insert a data on specific position in a text file, Python

Tags: python, text, file-handling

[image]

I need to calculate the fresh CRC and insert the updated value in the file on yellow highlighted place.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=CRC_END\n)(.*)(;)"


subst = "newvalue "

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, YOUR_STRING, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

for line in Lines:
count =count +1
if "CRC16" in line:
crcLineNumber = count

```
    Lines[crcLineNumber-1] = inputCrc[:-1].upper()+"h       ;   CRC16 - checksum, MSB - LSB\n"
    file1.close()
```